# create file at a restricted directory using gulp-dest

Tags: gulp

I have written an gulp script as :

```
    gulp.task('scss', function(done) {
  gulp.src('home/a.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
      errLogToConsole: true
    }))
    .pipe(rename('chatbot.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/var/www/html/css'))  // restrcited path
    .pipe(minifyCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .on('end', done);
});
```

here `/var/www/html/css` is a directory created via `sudo` hence no files can be created inside it normally.

so how can i create this file using gulp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `chown` to change the ownership of the folder, so that it belongs to your user account again: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership

Or you could try `sudo gulp scss`, I guess.